# How to make an element no larger than the enclosing element?

Tags: html, css, css-position

```
<div id="outer">
    <h2>blah</h2>
    <div id="inner"><!--content--></div>
</div>
```

`#outer` has a fixed, predefined size. I want `#inner` to always be within `#outer` (and if `#inner`'s content is too large then to make it scrollable).

"Solution":

```
#inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

THis solution is wrong since it makes `#inner`'s vertical size exactly the same as `#outer`'s, and since `#inner` is below `h2`, then it makes `#inner` ALWAYS go beyond `#outer`, which looks really ugly.

Now I don't know `h2`'s vertical size (since it depends on the font), and as far as I know CSS doesn't allow us to dynamically retrieve size of elements, so I can't do something like that:

```
#inner {
    height: calc(100% - getHeightOf(#outer>h3));
}
```

What is the solution to my problem? How can I make `#inner` never go outside `#outer`, no matter how large `#inner`'s content may be?

Comment: How about a [mcve]? I can't follow everything you are saying. Like you mention `<h3>` yet all I see in the scant HTML is a `<h2>`. Although I understand that the `<h2> `and `<h3>` are basically the same thing as far as what you are trying to explain, but I loose focus once one thing doesn't gist with the other. Hence code in the form of a [mcve] is much more succinct.

Comment: @zer00ne Sorry for that h2 / h3 mismatch, it's a typo.

Comment: Yes, as stated I know it's a typo. My point is you should make a [mcve] because a wall of text is not as descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scenario-1:** You don't want h2 content to be in fixed position. It will also scroll if inner content is overflow .

```css
#outer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  overflow: auto;
}
#inner{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <h2>blah</h2>
    <div id="inner">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Scenario-2**: You want h2 to be fixed in a sense that it should not scroll. The scroll bar should only be in inner div. In that case, use div instead of h2 and use definite height as shown below:

```css
#outer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.my-h2{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 10%;
}
#inner{
  height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="my-h2">blah</div>
    <div id="inner">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the `Overflow:scroll` property to the `outer`